# Windows 7 Bootcamp to see data doubler SATA SSD in Optical Bay Connector

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot-camp

Hi I purchased a OWC data doubler http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DDAMBS0GB/ ...
Long story short it lets you add a second HD to your macbook pro in place of the cd/dvd drive (which is useless anyway, impossible to get stuff out when stuck).

My current setup is 600gb intel SSD bootdrive 100gb partition for OSX / 500gb for Windows 7  Prof from Bootcamp (use 99 % of time).  My desire is to have a second 300gb SSD to run disk intensive VM's off of.  So I added a second 300gb intel SSD (again, NO desire to boot off of) on the sata optical port.  I can see the drive no problem if I boot in to OSX, however, can't see it in disk management on Win7 ??? Any ideas similar experience ...

Funny thing is I can see it in "Device Manager > Disk Drivers"  but not Disk Management ???

Also no I don't want to use Fusion/Parallels this is a waste of resources for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, have to uninstall drive from DISK DRIVES and re-install

Comment: If you answered your own questions, be sure to use the green check-mark to mark it as answered. It may help someone else in the future :)